# How to FIx Ubuntu?

Tags: freeze, crash, lts

I did my Ubuntu installation offline from a USB I burned an ISO I received from a friend to. Before installation, I used the 'check installation' feature. There was one problem or error I think. I ignored it, due to being offline before my install.

Since Installation, Ubuntu often freezes forcing me to force shut down(Hold the power btton). This only happens when I'm installing or updating software.

I also frequently run into errors, that ask me to send an error report. ( I click on send, but not sure how many sent due to poor connection.)

My internet connection is generally bad.

Is there a way to run diagnostics see what exactly my ubuntu problem is, and attempt to fix it. I do not want to have to reinstall Ubuntu.

My distro is: 16.04 LTS

Comment: that happens a lot. It happened to me too just ignore it restart your PC also don't try connecting to Internet when installing Ubuntu it will just freeze and you will have to do it over again.

Comment: If there was a problem with the installation image, it was a bad idea to ignore it. My advice, get a fresh image (not from a friend), make sure it's not corrupt, then reinstall.

Comment: Try to do updates from command line `sudo apt-get upgrade` and se if there are errors first. Or just try to check your installation with the usb

Comment: I am having some errors from sudo apt-get update. I've been able to download and update some apps though.

Is there a command I can run to check if my system is 'normal'?

Comment: From what you described, it's clear that "my system" is broken. If you really need a command, then `echo broken system` should do.